# How to code website so jscript from remote site is cached, rather than being constantly reloaded

Tags: html, css, performance, reload, javascript

Is there a way to get browsers visiting my site to cache external jscript, rather than reloading it every time they select another page on my site?  There's a banner/row on the top of the page with some buttons, and most of the buttons load different pages below the banner (not the one below, it opens a facebook page). The banner should be static. When the user loads different pages, the jscript/image (code below) disappears for 1/3 second until it reloads.  The other images on the banner are cached correctly and don't reload.

```
<div style="position: absolute; top:20px; right:85px; width:70px; height:25px">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1">
</script> 
<fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/somepage/somenum"layout="box_count"
show_faces="false" width="50"></fb:like>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're serving from another host, you can't change their expiration headers.

What you *could* do, is fetch those resources from your web server and serve them yourself with an updated expiration policy.  This might get sticky if the remote source wants to change their assets.

Comment: Can you direct me to a reference that talks about how I could try fetching and serving them myself, to see if it works?

Comment: You are saying there isn't a way to update the rest of my page and leave that element alone, so it's not reloaded?

Comment: I'd start with this Yahoo Answers post: http://developer.yahoo.com/dotnet/howto-rest_cs.html.  You can save the stream that you get as a file and reference that file from your pages.

Comment: Thanks. Big learning curve.  I had another idea, what if I put my own copy of the facebook like image on the page (updated with the right # of likes periodically) and when the user clicked on that, it THEN loaded and executed the script from the remote site (facebook)?  If doable, it seems the code to would be simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do anything about this. It's up for those scripts provider. In this example up for facebook.

Those scripts mostly load special data, thats why they are not cached.

Comment: You are saying there isn't a way to update the rest of my page and leave that element alone, so it's not reloaded?